# downloading mulitple images from a website and saving them in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bitmap, inputstream

I am working on a app where I would like to download images from a website and then save those images into a sqlite database. I tried already to find some good tutorials and the only thing that came close to what I would like to do, is a article by Tim Bray.

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

The code is really nice however it does not account for saving each single image. Bitmap unfortunatley (as far as I understand) does not distinguish between each image.

I would like to ask if anybody could give me some pointers or even better has source code for such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store images into a database you can store them as a BLOB-value.
Take a look here for that part: https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, this is a good tutorial. However is it possible when having more than one picture on that website to differentiate between them and add them each into a different row in the database?

Comment: As long as you manage to download them seperatly in your code that's no problem. Just create an auto increment field in your table. Then, when you insert the BLOB values each row will have an unique value.

For example if you create an field called ID (set it as an primary key and auto increment) this ID will increment automatically by 1 for each BLOB-value you insert.

Take a look here: http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html
and here http://www.devdaily.com/android/sqlite-autoincrement-serial-identity-primary-key

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Actually my problems lies with downloading the images seperatley. The images are located on a website, where they are printed in a row (which can be changed to boe printed in a column). The code in the tutorial only assumes that one picture is on that website. So how can I download them one by one?

Comment: I assume you know the URL of the images on the website?
In that case you can create an array and append all the image URL's to it. When that is done just create an for-loop where you iterate throught the array containing the image-urls and download them one by one and insert them into the database as they are downloaded.

Comment: Thanks Araw that is exactly what I needed. Very smart solution from your part. I was thinking about that problem for a while now and this never even crossed my mind. Thanks again for your patience and time. I would love give you a reputation point for this but unfortunatly i don't have the needed 15 points to do so.